# Server script files are showing while Remote debugging with visual studio 2017 windows 10

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I m able to connect to the server and attach to process sucessfully. But I m not able to see the server side script files to debug. the classic asp files are not appearing in the scrripts folder shown below.

But if I attach locallly I m able to see the files. what could be the problem ? please help.

screen shot of vs 2017 solution explorer
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkZPO.png

Comment: Please try [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019#:~:text=Select%20Configure%20remote%20debugging%20to,connection%20configuration%20in%20Visual%20Studio.) to use remote debug for your web project. Also, when you open `msvsmon.exe`, please select `Tools`-->`Options`--> set `no authentication` and `allow any user to debug`.

Comment: No luck, I m able to attach to process and connect to the remote debugger, but the asp files are not appearing in the solution explorer

Answer (score 0):

> Server script files are showing while Remote debugging with visual
> studio 2017 windows 10

It is quite strange and I have reported [the issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1176942/cannot-get-script-documents-folder-files-when-debu.html) on our **DC Forum**. You can vote it or add any comments if I did not describe the issue in detail.

And anyone who is interested in it will vote it  so that it will get more **Microsoft's** attention.